# Are hyphens correct in "jurisdiction-by-jurisdiction" or should spaces be used?

Tags: prepositions, punctuation, hyphenation, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

Are hyphens instead of word spaces OK in the following?

> Identification of existing trading relationships and operational requirements, jurisdiction-by-jurisdiction.

The above is from a document written in US English that I am checking, but I am not confident about correcting it as I'm a UK English speaker.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems to be a toss-up. Have a look at the following ngrams from the google corpus.

[image]

Comment: But that search conflates usage of the phrase as a compound modifier and as a simple adverbial phrase.

Answer (score 2):

It's allowed, but not compulsory, if you are using it as a compound, as you are here.

It's advisable (but still not compulsory) if you use it such a compound as a prepositive adjective, such as "on a jurisdiction-by-jurisdiction basis".